# Unable to run the beacon wallet integration on NextJS

Tags: wallets, beacon

I am building a chain-agnostic package for wallets called *Wallet01* and I am trying to implement **Beacon Wallet** for the tezos ecosystem.

I am using the **`@airgap/beacon-dapp`** package **`v4.0.4`**. I am using this package to build a custom connector for my project's purpose.

But when I try to build or run this package inside my NextJS app, it shows the following error.

```
Server Error
TypeError: (0 , solid_js_web__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.template) is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

You can find the relevant code here in this [pull](https://github.com/Huddle01/Wallet01/pull/21)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

If no NODE_ENV is set it defaults to production mode, setting the NODE_ENV explicitly to development will likely fix your issues afaik.

eg.

```
NODE_ENV=development npm run dev
```

You might need to add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true to your compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

Please let me know in the comment.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering, but this solution isn't working, the error still persists :D